# Regarding complex hashes in perl

Tags: perl, hash, perl-data-structures

I have a hash of hash, where my first key is name and second is some classes like `level A`, `level B`, `level C` and the values is d total number of students..

`%hash{name}->{class}->number`

So I fill my hash and everything is done but now when I print I get the number but if suppose a student name is in level A and level C and not in level B it should show

```
Name:level A = 1
     level B = 0
     level C = 1
```

How can I get my result like this? Please help me out..

Comment: Your question is not clear enough for me. Please post some code.

Comment: -1. Please be clearer in what you are asking, and for crying out loud, please write in English (not text speak). Some hints: Sentences start with a capital letter and end with one period, not two or three. The personal pronoun I is always capitalized. The correct spelling of 'nad' is 'and', 'everythin' is 'everything', 'numebr' is 'number'. Put a tiny bit more effort into your posts and the people here are much more likely to put an effort into writing a response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %scores = (
    homer => { levA => 1, levC => 2 },
    bart =>  { levA => 3, levB => 4 },
);

my %all_levels = map { map {$_ => 1} keys %$_  } values %scores;

for my $h (values %scores){
    for my $lev (keys %all_levels){
        $h->{$lev} = 0 unless exists $h->{$lev};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a stretch, but what I *think* you're after is  to assign a value of zero to all (name,class) pairs for which `$hash{name}->{class}` is undefined.  So, given that...

```
my @classes; #First, we grab all of the possible classes.

foreach my $name (sort keys %hash)
{
    foreach my $class (sort keys %{$hash->{$name}})
    {
        push @classes, $class unless $class~~@classes;
    }
}

@classes=sort @classes #or sort{$a<=>$b}@classes, depending on the datatype...

foreach my $name(sort keys %hash)
{
    foreach my $class(@classes)
    {
        $hash->{$name}->{$class}=0 unless defined $hash->{$name}->{$class};
    }
}
```